# How to read a latest downloaded file from a location using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Scenario :Suppose in a portal we have a link to download file every time user click on link and new file get downloaded how to check which is the latest file?

Comment: selenium is used to interact with a browser, you probably want another tool to interact with a filesystem to check if the file is there. You should be able to do this fairly easily through code or a small script. If you want to interact with the desktop, then it gets a little harder, but I'm not sure why you would want to do that if you just want to check if a file is there with a size greater than 0.

Comment: @mrfreester i would like to do that as i mention any time user click on download link a new file get downloaded so if user click on link for 3 time 3 file are getting downloaded eg:File_randomenumber_34567,File_randomenumber_34557,File_randomenumber_34807 so i need to search for the latest file and read the data from the file and compare data that of portal.

Comment: I think you might be better off searching stack overflow for questions on how to read data from files as this is more of a general programming type of a question.

Comment: You should ask a more specific question. The information you have provided is not enough. There are thousands of possible ways each relevant to its particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't use Selenium**.

Remember Selenium is the library that handles the communication between your test framework and the browser. Once the browser clicks to download a file Selenium has done its part and now you need to use **your test framework** to locate the file and perform any further non-browser actions.

Comment: Thank you it worked as mention in your comment @Chris Kenst

Comment: @Mr.Learner Great! Can you accept this answer as the final one?

Comment: yes i accept as the final answer that framework should handle it @Christ Kenst

Comment: @Mr.Learner great, you just need to click that check mark next to the answer to mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Kenst

Answer (score 0):

To check latest downloaded file you first need to download the file within a custom or specific directory. You can take help from [here](https://youtu.be/NQeEDfskP4c), where the procedure is explained using Selenium 4.9.1 Java and for Chrome & Firefox Browser v113.
Coming to the verification part - you have to iterate over all the downloaded file and check the `lastModifiedTime` of the file as below:

```
  Path file = Paths.get("/home/downloads/file123.txt");

  BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

  System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

Now create a current timestamp variable and calculate the difference. The file which has the lowest difference - is the latest file.